# add a woocommerce shop to every buddypress user

Tags: plugin-recommendation, buddypress, plugins

I'm creating a social network site with buddypress and woocommerce.
 I want to enable every member to purchase from others and to sell their products online.

> That is, every user must assigned to a woo-commerce category at the time of signup and their products will be listed in the sub of category.
>   For every category, there should be a separate pay-out account (like paypal).

I want to achieve this without using the buddypress-multisite feature.

What I am after:

> I want an idea behind it, any code snippets, examples or plugins.

All answers and suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show your thoughts so far. We haven't got that many advanced buddypress developers on the site, so you need to prepare your question as good as possible. Please use the edit function for your question.

Comment: Thanks @kaiser , According to your suggestion I've added some more details.

Comment: [According to our FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq), the site is here to _help_ doing tasks. You need to split your question in single manageable tasks and show your own effort in getting around it. So please go back again and narrow it down to a _specific_ problem.

Comment: Btw: A quick search on Google brought [this plugin](http://themekraft.com/woocommerce-buddypress-integration-your-social-network-shop/) by Themekraft.

Comment: @kaiser , I need any opensource plugin or an idea to develop this.

Comment: As I said, there're not that many users on [tag:buddypress], so your answer will likely not getting a satisfying answer. Your best bet would be to spend those 59 bucks (which is less than one developer hour) and look at its source if you think you need to roll your own.

Comment: @kaiser n, no user other than admin are unable to add their own product by themself :( which is essential.

Answer (score 4):

As th @kaiser's comment

> "Btw: A quick search on Google brought this plugin by Themekraft. –
>   kaiser Jul 25 at 14:30"

I bought [this PLUGIN](http://themekraft.com/woocommerce-buddypress-integration-your-social-network-shop/)

WooCommerce – BuddyPress Integration: 
Your Social Network Shop

Its working well and fulfills my need

Thanks to @kaiser.

Answer (score 0):

So after you purchased the plugin, there seems to be one problem left.

> *"Users are unable to add their own product by themself"*

I think this a problem with your user permission settings. Try the *"Members"*-plugin by Justin Tadlock to adjust your users roles capabilities. Maybe you're able to grant them the access.

Hint: Take a look at the post type that is used for products. Then search inside this Post Type object for the capability needed to `publish_posts`. WordPress internally maps all capabilities for post types to the default capability names of a "Post".

This means that you could have a capability named "say_amen", which is then mapped to "edit_others_posts" (and does exactly the same), but for a custom post type named "Allahs words".

Comment: Thanks, But It permits the user to edit all the products in the store. So, I started to code it :)

Comment: @VicKyAmr Hm? What exactly _permits the user to edit all the products in the store_ ? I just explained you how capabilities and custom post types work in WP, nothing else.